# What are these weird graphical artifacts?

Tags: graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a Samsung Series 7 laptop. It has the hybrid Radeon 6750M/Intel graphics. I've been getting weird artifacts sometimes now. They even happen in Lubuntu (in VirtualBox). It sort of looks like it is rendering in low-color, but Windows 7 is set to 32 bit. Both graphics drivers are updated, and I did try rolling back as well, but to no avail. They almost always manifest as those weird lines. In addition, it is not permanent; it seems to come and go. GPU-Z shows normal temperatures, and laptop doesn't run hot at all.

[image]

Comment: I see no such artifacts in the attached image.

Comment: Look below the button where it says "Solution 5". You can see the weird gradient below it. Like I said, it will go away, and come back, and it even changes intensity.

Comment: If you are seeing changing colors, it is most certainly a hardware issue. A static image will not reproduce the problem on other machines. It wouldn't even capture it, as the source image is not changing at all.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing except for some banding in the Samsung Recovery Solution icon, but that would be due to the color depth of the source image, and not what Windows is set to.

If it is elsewhere, perhaps it's your monitor? Have you tried with other monitors?

Comment: When I plug in an external monitor, it NEVER happens on the external monitor - only the laptop's display. It's not banding on the icon either, its off to the left and bottom of it. The few times it doesn't happen, you don't see the weird gradient at all.

Comment: @patricksweeny If it doesn't happen on the external monitor, and you can see it in the picture, but we can't, I also think it's a problem with your display.

Comment: @patricksweeney Yeah, your laptop display probably is malfunctioning.